# capture printing a file in wrapfs

Tags: c, file, file-io, linux-kernel, wrapper

I want to create a profile contains a history of files operations in a Wrapfs. I have code that detects when user create a new file, read or write exiting file. I want to add new feature to capture printing jobs, and sending files via email. So, my question is What are the file operations that I can use in Wrapfs to capture printing job and sending mails?

Any links to tutorials, sample code, or tips will be appreciated it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: the apps (`lp` or `mutt`) eventually should call `open()` and/or `read()` on the files, before sending them over the network/printer. If your implementation is correct, then you should be able to print out the application name from the `struct task_struct` along with the file name.

Comment: It's not my code. I tried it, and it works fine when I use vi, vim, and echo. However, it didn't work with lp.